# How to verify signatureBytes after signing it with SHA256withRSA?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am Signing some text using "Windows-MY"  KeyStore .
I want to sign using my private key and verify using Public Key.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
                keyStore.load(null, null); 
Enumeration en = keyStore.aliases();
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {   
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
                keyStore.load(null, null);
    String alias = en.nextElement().toString();
    X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
    String serialNumber = c.getSerialNumber().toString();
    System.out.println("--" + aliasName);
                PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(aliasName, null);
                PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) c.getPublicKey();
                Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(aliasName);
    DataOutputStream fout = new DataOutputStream(outstream);
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    String data = "Monika";
    byte[] content = data.getBytes();
    Provider p = keyStore.getProvider();
    // ----------------------signature---start---------------------------

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", p);
    System.out.println(" signature.getProvider():"+ signature.getProvider());
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(content);
    byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
    System.out.println("signatureBytes-------------"+ signatureBytes.toString());
    // ----------------------signature----------end------------------

    // ------------------------verification---------------
    Signature signature1 = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", p);
    System.out.println(" signature1.getProvider():"+ signature1.getProvider());
    signature1.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature1.update(content);
    boolean verifies = signature1.verify(signatureBytes);
    System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
    // ------------------------------------------------
    fout.close();
} // while
```

Output:

```
privateKey:RSAPrivateKey [size=2048 bits, type=Exchange, container=AC0BEBA9-A361-4611-96D9-B365B671FBC3]
 signature.getProvider():SunMSCAPI version 1.6
signatureBytes-------------[B@1402d5a
 signature1.getProvider():SunRsaSign version 1.5
signature verifies: false
```

### Notice that:

1. My Private key is already RSAPrivateKey .
2. Provider for Signing is SunMSCAPI.
3. But I dont know about Provider for Verification with PrivateKey.

Comment: My problem is resolved.. !!                                                                                    I simply updated java from 6 to 7 in my project , and it is working for me. Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: This is a Q/A site, Monika, not an online debugger. The questions and answers should match that. If you have resolved your question then you should post an answer. The current answers do not match your question anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA",p);
                        System.out.println(" signature.getProvider():"+ signature.getProvider());
                        signature.initSign(privateKey, new SecureRandom());
                        signature.update(byteData);
                        byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();




//                      X509Certificate cert1 =signatureBytes. 
                        System.out.println("signatureBytes-------------"+ signatureBytes.toString());
                        // ----------------------signature----------end------------------

                        // ------------------------verification---------------
                        Signature signature1 = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
                        System.out.println(" signature1.getProvider():"+ signature1.getProvider());
                        signature1.initVerify(publicKey);
                        signature1.update(byteData);

                        boolean verifies = signature1.verify(signatureBytes);
                        System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);
```

Comment: Please enter a description of what you did to resolve this. Just code is not considered an answer. Sorry to keep bugging you, but questions and answers on SO should be reusable by future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are simply using the **first** certificate / public key from your windows keystore. This might actually be the right one here, but there might be more than one certificate in the keystore and then it is just coincidence which certificate you are using for verify.

   ```
   String alias = en.nextElement().toString();
   X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
   PublicKey publicKey = c.getPublicKey();
   PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(DSCName, null);
   ```

   You should write `keyStore.getCertificate(DSCName)` instead to make sure it matches the private key.
2. You are generating a key (resp. trying to convert the existing key) for no reason. You can remove this code completely. This will also solve your problem with the NullPointerException:

   ```
   byte[] encodedPrivateKey = privateKey.getEncoded();
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
   RSAPrivateKey privateKey1 = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
   ```
3. There is a lot of unnecessary code in your question, like loading the certificate chain, but never using it. That makes it harder to fix. A minimal (working) example would look like this:

   ```
   String alias = "myAlias";
   String myData = "data to encrypt";

   KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
   keyStore.load(null, null);

   X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
   PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
   PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

   Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
   instance.initSign(privateKey, new SecureRandom());
   instance.update(myData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   byte[] signedBytes = instance.sign();

   instance.initVerify(publicKey);
   instance.update(myData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   System.out.println(instance.verify(signedBytes));
   ```

Comment: Did you try the code from my answer? Just put it in the main method of a new class and execute it. In most cases you don't need to explicitly pass a provider, Java choses the best suitable provider by itself.

Comment: @ Omikron: In the above answer, you mentioned SecureRandom() , is this a sun.security.SecureRandom() OR java.security.SecureRandom() ? I am trying to use it. It is asking for import.

Comment: It is java.security.SecureRandom

Comment: The code from my answer works here with a smart card that contains a private key and a matching certificate using Oracle Java 6 or 7. It also makes no difference if I specify a provider for Signature.getInstance() or not.

Comment: @ Omikron: But when i implemented  your answer as it is, it gives EXCEPTION: java.security.SignatureException: Invalid algorithm specified.           At line  :----------------------   System.out.println(instance.verify(signedBytes));

Comment: @MonikaTiwari Read point 1 from my answer again and try to understand it. You need to change only a single line (451) in your applet and it will work:  `X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(aliasName);` And maybe consider removing the while loop...

Comment: @MonikaTiwari Your applet works for me after this change. I have also  removed the key usage filter, so all certificates in the keystore are listed, but that should not matter. Maybe something is wrong with your token.

Comment: My problem is resolved.. !!                                                                                    I simply updated java from 6 to 7 in my project , and it is working for me. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `null` here

```
byte[] encodedPrivateKey = privateKey.getEncoded(); // are you sure that this byte array is not null ?
```

To make things more safe check here:

```
 PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(
                    DSCName, null); // this maybe returning null
```

so before the line which gives error, make a check:

```
if(encodedPrivateKey==null){
    System.out.println("private key is null");
}               
 PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                    encodedPrivateKey);
```

Comment: So, now figure out why it is `null` like I told you, you're not loading the `KeyStore` file, instead you're just passing `null` here `keyStore.load(null, null);`

Comment: @ Sharp edge:  I am not passing password cos it ask for password itself when i try to access private key.

Comment: you have to load the `KeyStore` in order to use it !

Comment: I can't check your code rite now because I'm on mobile, I'll give you a small tip! After each line do a `null check` for the above line object, you'll find out what is the actual cause that way.

Comment: I upvoted your question so that you could earn some reputation :)

Comment: My problem is resolved.. !!                                                                                    I simply updated java from 6 to 7 in my project , and it is working for me. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this complete and working code to verify **signature** after signing some text/data using digest **SHA256**with**RSA**:

```
/* verifyRSAsha256.java */
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/*
Compile:
clear && javac verifyRSAsha256.java && java verifyRSAsha256

Create private key:
openssl genrsa -des3 -out encrypted.pem 2048 && openssl rsa -in encrypted.pem -out private.pem -outform PEM && openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem

Create signature:
/bin/echo -n "some text that you want to be trusted" > data.txt
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem data.txt > signature.tmp
base64 signature.tmp

Verify signature:
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature signature.tmp data.txt
*/

public class verifyRSAsha256 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String publicKey = 
        //  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+
            "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwns0JWYgEshlpLYsZQFc"+
            "d5iVSqIHDO0zISLlO1aK4bbbosSvRE81+inKrG5mlnkIrv0+mJ/qTLY1RdBAVAe4"+
            "GPLTpHmLJhEtq7stydm2cCTEPRwfJNjoHqATDHEm1KLVGA8k0hztfMr8fLChE3/K"+
            "n2MHxzs7qhMLyBdPqbVC9RNja3i+Nl814xPTSXJ50zdJMLC56VtIU0xjqNjXN8iQ"+
            "pLZ2EfcP55nZ/venD01yxfsUn4sQLFTAlXqygA10fdDv9y0eZvgaGGSb4MuPT7yD"+
            "BfgNEU3tl4nRdSzPNkCkCmkuaa/pqZ5uw+G0HBwaQlHDwsnIcwE/xo6aHpt4xF4W"+
            "/QIDAQAB";
        //  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

        byte[] signature, data;

        // the signature is a binary data and I encoded it with base64, so the signature must be decoded from base64 to binary again
        signature = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("Yy9CdQDfdYWwZkSu2SZgoFABHk5Bd3tzYvX73QR+GDCWpUsWrO5CXRF+j3dBz+bq1SRQ+1c1hdez5mMeE1587s4Mos8EsT1sqNemu4l4535P+jYicwG1m2MAesquAHhIIAyY9iGID576ehX0/34rCCeGuVZablpL+2ki6cEwxPVlH7xtWNIc1AdxivHjkWorkWC1LrbfcNdbZhUrNuz7DZsxHP2sr+2TQdD4L9CA2bgpj6HeQt+MTfCf2PKSdVoLFdwnM8638jHL6MVcEJxeIow/YUDZGEAyR743RdRk4CGU1bJ7er9M1Q4hFfYWGOBsLBok2XXUJcchLgWET1eKdA==");

        // the signature length have to be 256 bytes
        System.out.print("Signature length 256 = ");
        System.out.println(signature.length);

        // the data used the generate the signature
        data = "some text that you want to be trusted".getBytes();

        // verify if signature is ok
        try {System.out.println(verify(data,signature,publicKey));}catch(GeneralSecurityException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        // if any byte of data changes (ex: change last byte from d to D)
        data = "some text that you want to be trusteD".getBytes();

        // the signature doesn't math and method verify will fail
        try {System.out.println(verify(data,signature,publicKey));}catch(GeneralSecurityException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    private static boolean verify(byte[] data, byte[] signature, String publicKey) throws GeneralSecurityException{
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(publicKey));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pubKey);
        sig.update(data);
        return sig.verify(signature);
    }
}
```

You can create a private and public key using openssl command line tool:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out encrypted.pem 2048 
openssl rsa -in encrypted.pem -out private.pem -outform PEM
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout > public.pem
```

You can create one signature with your private key using openssl command line tool:

```
/bin/echo -n "some text that you want to be trusted" > data.txt
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem data.txt > signature.tmp
```

You can verify if the signature is correct using openssl command line tool:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature signature.tmp data.txt
```